# link div to input text in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps api to have a map show up on my website where visitors can also find directions. I have a starting point setup and an end point. Both are text areas. The start is empty, but I want the end point to be populated with the address from a div that I already have in the page. I have the javascript as:

var address = document.getElementById("address").innerText.replace(/\n/g, " ");

It works in Chrome, but Firefox shows the text in the endpoint box as 'undefined.' And Firebug is giving me -

document.getElementById("address").innerText is undefined
[Break On This Error] var address = document.getElementB...ress").innerText.replace(/\n/g, " ");

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: i think it has something to do with replace(/\n/,g,""). whenever I put that in the code, it doesn't show up as undefined, it just stays blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`.

if that doesn't work how you want it to, try:

`var address = element.innerText || element.textContent;`

Answer (score 0):

figured it out...

just need to replace innerText with textContent for firefox.